# Заменить свойство modelState на, например, error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

Добрый день.

Создание нового пользователя:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(IdentityUser user)
 {
      var addUser = await AppUserManager.CreateAsync(user);

      if (!addUser.Succeeded)
      {
          return GetErrorResult(addUser);
      }
      // Что-то делаем дальше.
 }
```

Метод GetErrorResult()

```
 protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
 {
     if (result == null)
     {
         return InternalServerError();
     }
     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
         return null;
     }
     if (result.Errors != null)
     {
          foreach (var error in result.Errors)
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError("Errors", error);
          }
     }
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {               
         return BadRequest();
     }

     return BadRequest(ModelState);
 }
```

Если, например, email уже зарегистрирован придет сообщение вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать, каким образом заменить `modelState` на, например `error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `GetErrorResult()` замените

```
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

на следующий код:

```
var modelState = ModelState.Select(p => new { key = p.Key, errors = p.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage) })
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.key, kv => kv.errors);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "", Error = modelState });

return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!